# Rate at which bullets strike a stationary target when gun in motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

In determining the power radiated by a point charge in motion, Griffths' Introduction to Electrodynamics notes one subtle point concerning the rate at which electromagnetic energy leaving the charge is not equal to the rate at which energy passes through some large sphere centred on the charge.

To explain what is happening he notes that for someone in a moving car, shooting at a fixed target the rate $N_t$ at which the bullets reach the target is different from the rate $N_g$ at which the bullets are fired.

[image]

Griffiths' gives the result between $N_t$ and $N_g$ as $$N_t = \frac{N_g}{1 - v/c},$$
where $v$ is the speed of the car and $c$ is the speed of the bullets, both relative to the ground. Can anyone show me how to derive this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in essence a slight rewording of the Doppler shift problem. In your case, the rates $N_g$ and $N_t$ are representative of the the frequencies usually used in the problem.

In some time $\frac{1}{N_g}=T$, the source travels a distance $vT$ and hence the apparent "wavelength" is shortened by this amount such that we get $\lambda'=\lambda-vT$. Since you know the speed of the bullets to be $c$, you can easily convert the wavelength to a frequency. Putting all this together you get that

$N_t = \frac{c}{\lambda - (v/N_g)}$

If you rearrange the terms you will find that you arrive at the result stated by Griffith. [HyperPhysics](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Sound/dopp.html) has a nice explanation of this aswell.

Comment: You shouldn't really provide full solutions for homework-style questions.